# Git unstaged changes back after checkout mistake on entire repository working copy

Tags: git

I have lost unstaged changes with:

```
git checkout 4cf0e6e88821c0c55a8897d264784c05454702a8^ -- ./
```

Then, I tried to use these command to get it back:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD
git reset --hard 4cf0e6e
```

But none of these allowed me to got back to my uncommitted changes.

Are my changes lost for ever or is there still a way to get it back ?

Comment: Did you add the uncommitted changes?

Comment: @ElpieKay no, I didn't

Comment: If you didn't add them and your editor doesn't have any auto backup function, they are just lost. As far as I know the only hope is a disk data recovery tool. If they are still open in the editor like vs-code, ctrl-z could help.

Comment: Indeed, ctrl-z saved me on vs-code!! Thanks a lot!! Other changes lost should be minor changes.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Git stores the file content when the file is added. Think twice before running `git checkout <paths>` or `git reset --hard` if the files have not been added.

Comment: Commit early, commit often.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Actually, I should have said "unstaged" changes instead of "uncommitted" in the title... I'll modify it.

Comment: @DevonDahon stage early. Stage often. 